# Bootstrap input-append & input-prepend

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on [this website](http://www.promap.ca/form.html) and trying to find why the `.input-prepend` and `.input-append` are behaving like this is all Viewport Width smaller than 1027.

[image]

Comment: The website noted in this question is now inaccessible, so this question can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet you have the following viewport rule:

```
/*This Part is for iPhone 4 Portraite*/ 
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .tabres{padding:0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
  .cent{text-align: center;}
  .respo{padding:7px;}
  .table-striped{font-size:95%; margin-bottom:5px;}
  .span3{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
  }
```

You are setting margin-top of all `span3` elements (which the input fields are one of) to 5px when the viewport is less than 480px.

In my browser that's the only viewport being affected.

Comment: Thanks Jivings I test this in Firefox and Chrome and same issues on both browsers were happening!